# tk.Text: Tag Font

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to get a proper `Font` instance out of a tag, so I can change just the size? I know I can dump it in `tk.font.Font` but that seems really inefficient.

```
for tag in self.tag_names():
    #I need `f` to be a Font instance, not just a string
    f = self.tag_cget(tag, 'font')
```

Comment: A small code example illustrating what you are speaking about would be sure helpful ...

Comment: @Claudio ~ OK, done.

Comment: From the three lines of provided code is still unclear how it comes that >"**hundreds** of arbitrary font instances are made just to change a size".

Comment: @Claudio - you are entirely focussed on the wrong part. If I kept dumping `f` into `Font` it could make millions of arbitrary instances. It all depends on how often the font size is changed in the example loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to premake all of the `Font` instances and assign the instances to the applicable tag's `font` option. When you want to change the sizes, loop over the stored `Font` instances, and change their sizes directly. Every tag that uses your `Font` instances will change accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you used font objects to create the tags, then you can get the font name from the tag and then use `nametofont` to convert it to an instance of `tkinter.font.Font`. However, this only works if the tag has a font associated with it, and if the font is a font object rather than shorthand notation (eg: `("Helvetica", 24, "bold")`).

```
from tkinter.font import nametofont
...
for tag_name in self.tag_names():
    font_name = self.tag_cget(tag_name, "font")
    if font_name:
        font = nametofont(font_name)
        size = int(font.cget("size"))
        font.configure(size = size + delta)
```

Comment: I tried this. It kept telling me the name doesn't already exist. I tried using the `name` option, and a number of other things. However, I don't think this approach is best, for me. I have 4 fonts, and it's really just one font in 4 styles. I just loop over them and change their size directly. I do want to try what you suggested again, though. I just want to understand what I did wrong. Thank you for being the first person to ever give me an answer! I really do need help when I ask these questions. I just don't wait for answers.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy: _" It kept telling me the name doesn't already exist."_ - then you need to figure out why. It will tell you that if you didn't create a font object for the tag, like my answer says. You would also probably get this if you had more than one instance of `Tk` in your program.  If you want to find out what you did wrong, please edit your question to include a complete (but minimal!) [mcve] that we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy: if you only have four fonts, it makes the most sense just to directly modify those four font objects rather than go through the trouble of iterating over the tags.

Comment: "It will tell you that if you didn't create a font object for the tag" ~ Well, I literally looped over every tag after they were all created (some by idlelib) and reassigned the "font" option with a `Font` instance.  I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm just telling you what I did. Maybe garbage collection picked them up since they were only assigned to the "font" option and not a persisting reference. However, if that's the case, `nametofont` deprecated itself. If I have a persisting reference to the font, I don't need `nametofont`.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy: since you haven’t given us a way to reproduce the problem, we can only make guesses. Please provide a [mcve]. Arguably the best solution is to create persistent references to the font objects.

Comment: I haven't provided an example because my problem is solved, and the side conversation we are having is secondary to this question. If you want to reproduce the problem, put an arbitrary `Font` instance on a tag (`self.tag_configure(tagname, font=Font(...))`), and then later on in the script try your above solution on it, because that's exactly what I did.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy: if that information had been in your question we could have avoided this long conversation, and we could have addressed the root problem.